# How do I round this int up

Tags: c

Is there any way to round `systemGuess` up. In this case the outcome of `systemGuess` is 5.5 I want it to be 6 how do I do this?

See code below:

```
 int main(void){

    int systemGuess = 0;
    stystemGuess = (10 - 1)/2 + 1;
    printf(" %d ", stystemmGuess);
}
```

Comment: If you want to round normally, add `.5` to the total before assigning to stystemGuess.

Comment: It depends on the rounding rules you are trying to apply. Do you want to round all results of integer division up, or round to the nearest integer with a tie-break rule for .5, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use floating point division and `ceil`:

```
stystemGuess = ceil((10 - 1)/2.0) + 1;
```

If you want to round 0.4 down, use `round` instead.

Comment: "If you want to round 0.4 down, " --> use `floor()`.  `round()` is for rounding to nearest and ties handled in a defined way.

Comment: @chux I meant 'if you want to round `0.5` up and `0.4` down'.

Comment: OK - OP's is a bit unclear about quotients in the (0.0 ... 0.5) range.

Answer (score 1):

OP wants to perform an integer division with the result rounded-up.

```
// If the quotient fraction > 0, return next larger number.
unsigned udiv_ceiling(unsigned n, unsigned d) {
  return (n + d - 1)/d;
}

// If the quotient fraction >= 0.5, return next larger number.
unsigned udiv_nearest_ties_up(unsigned n, unsigned d) {
  return (n + d/2)/d;
}

stystemGuess = udiv_ceiling(10 - 1, 2) + 1;
// or
stystemGuess = udiv_nearest_ties_up(10 - 1, 2) + 1;
```

Additional code needed to handle negative numbers and in corner cases, protect against `n + d - 1` overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
systemGuess = (10 - 1)/2.0 + 1 + 0.5;
```

The problem is that you do integer calculation.
So e.g. 9/2 is 4. If you use 9/2.0 you have floating point division, which gives you 4.5. Adding 0.5 in the end gives you 6.0 instead of 5.5, so when storing it in `systemGuess`, you get 6 instead of 5.

Comment: Not everyone here is dutch.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the question with those Dutch (?) variables names. Changed it

Answer (score 0):

Integer division in C [truncates toward 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c), so if you do the math on the other side of 0 (i.e., on negative numbers), it will "round up". You might do this by subtracting an amount from the dividend and adding half that amount back to the result:

```
int main(void)
{
    int systemGuess = 0;
    //systemGuess = (10 - 1)/2 + 1;
    systemGuess = (10 - 1 - 20)/2 + 1 + 10;
    printf(" %d ", systemGuess);
}
```

Probably in your real program there is a more elegant way to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int divide(int x, int y);

int main(void){

    int systemGuess = 0;

    int x = 10-1;
    int y = 2; 

    systemGuess = divide(x,y) + 1;

    printf(" %d ", systemGuess);

}

int divide(int x, int y) {
   int a = (x -1)/y +1;
   return a;
}
```